# What would be a type of an event in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, variable-types

I'm trying to specify the types of all my methods/parameters so instead of:

```
someCoolFunction(param) { ... }
```

I try to use the type safe'ish version like this:

```
someCoolFunction(param: number): void { ... }
```

When I bounce around types that I've declared myself, it's easy. When it comes to types brought from other packages, I also often know what they are as I explicitly specify my imports.

However, I'm not sure what type to give to the event, to the object and to the output in the method below.

```
someBoundFunction(event, junk) {
  ...
  return {a: 1, b: 2};
}
```

I've seen `any` being used but I'm not sure if it's applicable in this case. Also, I'm sensing that it's just incorrect for the event call. (If it matters, the call binding to the function can look as below.)

```
<custom-thing (output)="someBoundFunction($event, {x:"x",y:"y"})">!</custom-thing>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but in this case the type of `$event` can vary. `$event` is just a proxy for whatever is transmitted via the `emit` method in `custom-thing`.

For example, if I had an output on my component called `output`.

```
@Output() output: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

emitEvent() {
   this.output.emit(5); // $event is 5 of type number
}
```

Comment: If you are writing the component `custom-thing` you may know the type of the `output` EventEmitter, in which case you could include the type.

Comment: If it is a DOM event, like a MouseEvent, you can find a list of Typescript types [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts).

Answer (score 2):

'any' is ok because function `someBoundFunction` in template is dynamically binding -  (via angular2 template parser) so TS don't know type (TS not parse templates - they are dynamically parsed by angular2).

Of course to 'visual clarify' you can use `someBoundFunction(event: SomeType, junk: any): any` the same as you use in `@Output() output: EventEmitter<SomeType> = new EventEmitter();` (in custom-thing component) but it will be not check by TS parser (due to unable to parse and bind function in template). You can use 'any' as return `someBoundFunction` type because you not defined object `{a: 1, b: 2}` type as separate class (but as dynamically created object) - and the same situation is for `{x:"x",y:"y"}`.

=== EDIT ===

@AluanHaddad in comments below give me some new informations about TS (thanks) that I don't know before so the new version of my answer is:

Define `outputData` interface (or class) (because it will be used twice: on event emit and event handling) e.g.:

```
export interface OutputData {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}
```

Then in your `custom-thing` component define event:

```
@Output() public output = new EventEmitter<OutputData>();
```

And fire event:

```
this.output.emit({a:'test', b:2});
```

And then you can define event handler `someBoundFunction` in this way:

```
public someCoolFunction(event: OutputData, junk: {a: string, b:string}) : { a: number, b: number} {
    // ...
    return { a: 1, b:2};
}
```

And because you return some object in `someCoolFunction` so I assume that you want reuse this function in other part of code - so you can invoke it by (if you don't want to reuse this handler, defining `junk` type and return type is unnecessary):

```
let result = this.someCoolFunction({ a: 'test', b: 666}, { a:1, b:'zz'});
console.log(result.a); 
// ...
```

And now you have pretty strong typeized code (except `someCoolFunction` type checking in template).

Comment: What would *SomeType* be in this case? It's supposed to be the event that Angular sends in to the method (the usual, very much like JS event with all the positions, target info etc. specified)...

Comment: Try `EventEmitter`

Comment: When you define event `@Output() output: EventEmitter<SomeType> = new EventEmitter()` in your component `custom-thing` you can defined `SomeType` as you want (as separate class - it depends what you will return in event by `this.output.emit(objectOfSomeType)`)

Comment: Absolute nonsense, and bad advice too.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Would you care to elaborate, please?

Comment: @AndyJ, Graztok's answer is the correct. Also it should be noted that `any` should be avoided wherever possible because it disables type checking. Another thing is that this answer makes some claim about "_due to unable to bind function in template_" which is bogus because TypeScript does not parse templates. Another bogus claim in this answer is "_You can use 'any' as return someBoundFunction type because you not defined object {a: 1, b: 2} type as separate class (but as dynamically created object) - and the same situation is for {x:"x",y:"y"}_", which is flat out wrong.

Comment: @AluanHaddad there was some english-language mistake (i'm not native - sorry about that). Of course TS not parse templates - angular2 parse it. I will a little corect my answer. Second thing you say that my sentence: _"you can use 'any' as return someBoundFunction type because you not defined object {a: 1, b: 2} type as separate class (but as dynamically created object) - and the same situation is for {x:"x",y:"y"}"_ - its wrong - could you explain why?

Comment: No problem. It is because `{a: 1, b: 2}` has a type: `{a: number, b: number}`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes but that type `{a: number, b: number}` has no name :) because is dynamically created (not as separate named class). Because we don't have type name - we are unable to use it in `someBoundFunction ` function definition.

Comment: Sorry hit enter too soon. But basically that is a type literal. We can use it easily, we can alias it with `type T = {a: number, b: number};`, or we can converted to an `interface`. The key point is that classes are not even the primary source of types let alone the only source. Interfaces and type literals are much more elemental to the language.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski oh but you can. `f(x: {a: number , b: number}): {name: string, age?: number}`

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski basically the key thing I'm trying to say is: don't learn TypeScript from angular tutorials! Read the typescript handbook instead.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski much much better. However, you should use an `interface`, not a `class` declaration because the latter will allow invalid use.